# Error : [AppRoutes] is not a <Route> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am currently working on React-Router with this tutorial
https://blog.logrocket.com/complete-guide-authentication-with-react-router-v6/

this is my App.jsx

```
import {
  Route,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  defer,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Root from "./src/routes/root";
import SignIn from "./src/routes/sign-in";
import SignUp from "./src/routes/sign-up";
import Dashboard from "./src/routes/dashboard";
import { HomeLayout } from "./src/components/HomeLayout";
import { AuthLayout } from "./src/components/AuthLayout";
import { ProtectedLayout } from "./src/components/ProtectedLayout";
import ProfilePage from "./src/routes/profile";
import { useAuth } from "./src/hook/useAuth";

const AppRoutes = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
      <Route element={<HomeLayout />}>
        <Route path="/" element={isAuthenticated ? <Dashboard/> : <Root />} />
        <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignIn />} />
        <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
      </Route>

      <Route path="/user" element={<ProtectedLayout />}>
        <Route path="profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  )
};

export const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <AppRoutes />
  )
);
```

I want the `"/"` to render the `Dashboard` component if authenticated, else rendering `Root`. I have the error "[AppRoutes] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`".

Answer (score 0):

`AppRoutes` isn't a `Route` component, so it can't be rendered as one. To fix, render `AppRoutes` ***on*** a route.

Example:

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="*" element={<AppRoutes />} />
  )
);
```

`AppRoutes` itself also can't render directly any `Route` components, they must be direct children of the `Routes` component. Please also ensure you are importing all the required components.

Example:

```
import {
  Route,
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
...

const AppRoutes = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<AuthLayout />}>
        <Route element={<HomeLayout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={isAuthenticated ? <Dashboard/> : <Root />} />
          <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUp />} />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/user" element={<ProtectedLayout />}>
          <Route path="profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  )
};
```

Comment: im still getting error with "Route component" problem but I have another error: Unexpected Application Error!
Cannot destructure property 'isAuthenticated' of 'useAuth(...)' as it is undefined.

Comment: @ChâuĐặng Oh, sorry, the `AppRoutes` component also needs to wrap all the `Route` components in a `Routes` component. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/error-approutes-is-not-a-route-component-mq4c35) demo. The `useAuth` hook return value seems like a separate issue. Double-check its return value. If you need more specific help for the `useAuth` hook issue then it would be better to create a new post specific to that problem. If you do create a post then feel free to ping me here with a link to the post and I can take a look when available.

Comment: @ChâuĐặng Has your question/issue been sufficiently addressed/resolved?